# Docker-compose volumes to map to external usb drive

Tags: docker-compose

I would like to map an external usb drive in my docker-compose.yml I used the following:

```
 volumes:
 external: true
  #- bitcoin-data:/data original line commented out to attempt next line
   - bitcoin-data:/run/media/directory name/external drive name/docker-base
```

However when running docker-compose up I receive the following:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 8
```

Line 5 refers to the image and Line 16 refers to the external drive I am 
 attempting to save data destination.

Comment: Hello @luemob! Is the answer provided helped you? If not, could you please comment about? If yes, I kindly invite you to mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a list in a yaml file just after a variable, that's why you have this error. If you want to add the `external` parameter, you will have to put the volumes's path into you container section, and the `external` setting into the volumes section, like:

```
services:
  yourcontainer:
    [...]
    volumes:
        - bitcoin-data:/run/media/directory name/external drive name/docker-base

volumes:
  bitcoin-data:
    external: true
```